# RFC question about cookies and paths

Tags: http, authentication, cookies, rfc

I'm trying to set a session cookie restricted to a particular path (let's say `/foo`) when a user logs in. The complication being that the login page is on `/`, but the request immediately redirects to `/foo/something`. Something like this:

Request:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1

username=foo&password=bar
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Location: http://example.com/foo/home
Set-Cookie: session=whatever; path=/foo
```

However, the relevant bits of the RFCs I could find ([rfc2109](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt) and [rfc2965](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2965.txt)) say this:

> To prevent possible security or privacy violations, a user agent
>   rejects a cookie (shall not store its information) if any of the
>   following is true:
>
> - The value for the Path attribute is not a prefix of the request-
>     URI.
>
> ...

The cookie-setting process described above seems to *work* okay, but as far as I can tell the RFCs are saying it shouldn't.

I'd like to use this in a production system, but I really don't want to do that if I'm going to face horrible browser incompatibility problems later.

Am I misreading the RFCs?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pay any attention to those RFCs; they diverge from reality pretty badly.

There's currently an IETF WG that's documenting actual cookie behaviour; their document, while just a draft, is much better source material.

See:
  http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-httpstate-cookie/

If you don't find text that addresses your question in the draft, bring it up with the Working Group!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I think  your understanding of the RFC is correct.  It sounds like you want to set the cookie after the redirect to ***'/foo/home'***.  I think the real question is: "How do you tell ***'/foo/home'*** that the user was authenticated correctly by ***'/'***?"

If you must use a Location header (redirect) to get from ***'/'*** to ***'/foo/home'***, it seems the only way to do this would be to use a query string parameter in the Location header's value.

Maybe a design question to consider is:  why are users authenticating against a URL outside of the path they will be accessing securely?  If the only secure content is under ***'/foo'***, then why not POST to ***'/foo/login'*** instead of ***'/'*** for authentication?